# In this cash game, why did they 're-deal' the river?

Tags: texas-hold-em, poker-theory, poker-strategy

Re [Garrett Adelstein and Robbi Jade Lew](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/11902/if-robbi-jade-lew-is-cheating-how), why do they 're-deal' or whatchamacallit the river from ace of spades to 9 of diamonds? See 4:16 onwards [here](https://youtu.be/lXoWZE90n28?t=256). I've seen things like this in, say, blackjack, but poker I've never seen...at least texas hold 'em. I think I've seen other poker variants that are like this.

**Guess**: Somehow there's a rule where all players who haven't folded can agree to re-deal.

Comment: Hey @BCLC, this is a valid question, but I think the way you've phrased this is confusing for people. Specifically attributing this to the Garrett and Robbi hand is what I mean. Also some of the tags like cheating aren't valid. This is a very common practise in cash games, andrewchin gave a nice answer below. I've edited the title and removed the tag.

Comment: @Grinch91 I'm a n00b in poker. Maybe that's why it's confusing? Or you mean still confusing for other reasons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as *Running it twice*.

When this happens, half the pot is awarded to the winner of the first full runout, and half the pot is awarded to the winner of the second full runout.  In the case of the hand in reference, we have Jc4h vs 8c7c in two runouts:  the first being Th Tc 9c 3h 9d, and the second being Th Tc 9c 3h As.  Since Jc4h has the better hand in both runouts, Robbi was awarded both halves of the pot.

Comment: thanks Andrew Chin. 1 - so it's a thing a tournament may or may not have? or all/most (texas hold 'em?) tournaments have run it 2x? 2 - ok i hear at 4:25 the commentators say they run it twice aaaand going back to [3:26](https://youtu.be/lXoWZE90n28?t=206) after robbi calls...someone says 'run it twice' or something...was that the dealer who said that like the dealers always ask players after someone's all in? 3 - ok so it looks like garrett says 3:40 says 'up to you' ...at what point exactly does robbi agree to the run it twice please? I guess before 3:55 when Robbi says 's()tty hand' ?

Comment: 4 - another thing...thinking about this a lot more: Does the run it 2x DECREASE, even if not by much, the probability that robbi was cheating? It's 1 thing to say see the top card (past the burn) but to see that BOTH the top 2 cards aren't going to be clubs? [That's weird, I mean that's completely insane.](https://twitter.com/anishgiri/status/1575753962833125376)

Comment: This answers the ruling that allows the action and explains the action, as in "what" they did, but it doesn't answer "why" - running it twice is usually done to remove variability, so even if the favourite hand loses by minuscule odds, it'd be astronomically unlikely to lose both times (partially because hitting once removes a card from the outs odds from the second time) and the agreement to run it twice typically only happens when both parties think they have the strongest hand. There is no way a jack high will be the strongest hand.

Comment: @Unihedron oh thanks. I didn't really mean to ask 'why' like strategically. Just what's up with the double river.

Comment: Re my 4th follow up: full post: https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/11915/re-garrett-adelstein-and-robbi-jade-lew-does-running-it-twice-decrease-cheating

Comment: Re my 2nd and 3rd follow up: full post: https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/11923/robbi-and-garrett-run-it-twice